# Excel Conditional Formatting By Day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello I need to add conditional formatting to a date field to determine whether the inputted date is a Sunday, if this is not the case, I need the field to be highlighted, any advise?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(YOUR_DATE;2)=7;"PAINT";"NOT PAINT")
```

Use the formula `WEEKDAY` to return the day of week,

WEEKDAY("YOUR_DATE";2) this 2 determine the format of your week in my case week starts on Monday so monday is 1 and Sunday is 7 that's why I put "2"